# Using .filter to compare two arrays and return values that aren't matched

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues comparing the elements of two arrays and filtering out matching values. I only want to return array elements that are NOT included within `wordsToRemove`.

```
var fullWordList = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var wordsToRemove = ['1','2','3'];

var filteredKeywords = fullWordList.forEach(function(fullWordListValue) {
    wordsToRemove.filter(function(wordsToRemoveValue) {
        return fullWordListValue !== wordsToRemoveValue
    })
});

console.log(filteredKeywords);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to achieve this:

```js
var fullWordList = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var wordsToRemove = ['1','2','3'];

var filteredKeywords = fullWordList.filter((word) => !wordsToRemove.includes(word));

console.log(filteredKeywords);
```

Answer (score 3):

use filter and includes to perform this

```js
var fullWordList = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var wordsToRemove = ['1','2','3'];

var newList = fullWordList.filter(function(word){
   return !wordsToRemove.includes(word);
})
console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty easy to do using `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
var fullWordList = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var wordsToRemove = ['1','2','3'];

var filteredKeywords = fullWordList.filter(
  word=>!wordsToRemove.includes(word)
//or
//word=>wordsToRemove.indexOf(word)<0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` on `fullWordList` is not required, use `filter` on `fullWordList` and `indexOf()` in your function in `filter()` to check if a number exists in `wordsToRemove` or not.

```js
var fullWordList = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var wordsToRemove = ['1','2','3'];

var newList = fullWordList.filter(function(x){
   return wordsToRemove.indexOf(x) < 0;
})
console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try

```
var fullWordList = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var wordsToRemove = ['1','2','3'];
var match = [];

for(let word of fullWordList){
    if(!wordsToRemove.find((val) => val == word))match.push(word);
}
```