# how can take a property in object between 2 array difference

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = [{a: '1', b: '1'}, {a: '2', b: '2'}]
var b = [{a: '2', b: '2'}, {a: '3', b: '23'}]
var c = a.map(itema => {if (b.some(itemb => itemb. a !== itema.a)) return {a: itema.a}})
console.log(c);
```

---

```
// result
c = [{a: '1'}, {a: '2'}]

// expected
c = [{a: '1'}]
```

Comment: Please clarify your question or give a details.

Comment: You are looping through the array, it's going to return results based on the elements in the looped array and the length will be that of the looped array.

Comment: Question is not clear what you want. Please clarify

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599749/using-filter-to-compare-two-arrays-and-return-values-that-arent-matched , may be this can give you idea

Comment: find out a object in array A not in array B. and then just take one of property in  object has found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Array.map()` alone,  use `Array.filter()` to filter out the array based on the condition and than use `Array.map()`:

```js
var a = [{a: '1', b: '1'}, {a: '2', b: '2'}];
var b = [{a: '2', b: '2'}, {a: '3', b: '23'}];
let c = a.filter(o =>!b.some(ob=> ob.a == o.a)).map(o=>Object.assign({}, {a: o.a}));
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear though as per your desire output you can use below code.

```
var a = [{a: '1', b: '1'}, {a: '2', b: '2'}]
var b = [{a: '2', b: '2'}, {a: '3', b: '23'}]
var c = a.reduce( (arr, itema) => { if (!b.reduce( (flag,itemb) => { return flag || itemb.a == itema.a }, false )) { arr.push({a: itema.a}) } return arr } , []);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `b.every` instead of `b.some` and then a `filter()` at the end to filter out the `undefined` values you get from `map()`:

```js
var a = [{
  a: '1',
  b: '1'
}, {
  a: '2',
  b: '2'
}]
var b = [{
  a: '2',
  b: '2'
}, {
  a: '3',
  b: '23'
}]
var c = a.map(itema => {
  if (b.every(itemb => itemb.a !== itema.a)) 
  return {
    a: itema.a
  }
}).filter(item => item);
console.log(c);
```