# Javascript map obejct in array of objects add new object to array if condition not met

Tags: javascript

Not sure why I struggle so much with javascript and object methods, but it makes my brain hurt. I'm receiving backend data and need to compare values in a nested array of objects to an array of dates and add in an object if the match is not there.

Data:

```
[{
  _id: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  fullName: "Johnny Cochrane",
  contracts: {
    type: "Quarterly",
    hours: 120,
  },
  client: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  hours: [{
    date: "2023-5",
    count: 6,
  }, {
    date: "2023-6",
    count: 2,
  }],
}, {
  _id: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
  fullName: "Sheila Thompson",
  contracts: {
    type: "Quarterly",
    hours: 140,
  },
  client: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
  hours: [{
    date: "2023-4",
    count: 5.5,
  }, {
    date: "2023-6",
    count: 2,
  }],
}]
```

Setting the dates for comparing and prepping for table headers:

```
const qtrs = [{qtr: 1, mths: [1,2,3]}, {qtr: 2, mths: [4,5,6]}, {qtr: 3, mths: [7,8,9]}, {qtr: 4, mths: [10,11,12]} ]

const currentMth = new Date().getMonth() + 1

const currentQtr = qtrs.filter(({mths}) => mths.includes(currentMth))

const compDates = currentQtr[0].mths.map(i => new Date(new Date(new Date().setMonth(i)).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString())
```

The section I'm struggling with to massage the data for the table:

```
const adjust = data.forEach(i => {
  i.hours.forEach(item => {
  console.log("item1: ",item)
  const interim = new Date(item.date).getMonth() + 1
  console.log(interim)
  item.date =  new Date(new Date(new Date().setMonth(interim)).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString()
  console.log(item.date)

//Steps I've tried- 1st:
cursor = 0
Object.entries(item).map(obj => {console.log(obj); compDates[cursor] && compDates[cursor] == obj.date ? {...obj} :{count: 0, date: obj.date, total: obj.total}});

//2nd try
Object.values(item).map(x => (compDates.find(y => y === x.date) ? {...x}: {count: 0, date: x.date, total: x.total}))

//3rd
if (compDates.find(y => y === item.date)) {
    item = item
  } else {
   item = {count: 0, date: item.date, total: item.total}
  } 


})})
```

I've messed around trying Object.values, Object.keys along with Object.entries, and changing the function. I know any one of those should be able to work, I'm just clueless as to what I'm missing to get the response right.

My ideal output with this data would be:

dates being compared:
["2023-05-16T07:00:00.258Z", "2023-06-16T07:00:00.258Z", "2023-07-16T07:00:00.258Z"]

```
[{
  _id: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  fullName: "Johnny Cochrane",
  contracts: {
    type: "Quarterly",
    hours: 120,
  },
  client: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  hours: [{
    date: "2023-4", // this does not need to be changed back from the ISO date in the comparison stage
    count: 0,
  }, {
    date: "2023-5",
    count: 6,
  }, {
    date: "2023-6",
    count: 2,
  }],
}, {
  _id: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
  fullName: "Sheila Thompson",
  contracts: {
    type: "Quarterly",
    hours: 140,
  },
  client: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
  hours: [{
    date: "2023-4",
    count: 5.5,
  }, {
    date: "2023-5", // again does not need to be changed back
    count: 0,
  }, {
    date: "2023-6",
    count: 2,
  }],
}]
```

Comment: The Array.map method returns a new array and doesn't modify the input array so you need to assign the result. The tries 1 anf 2 can't have any effect line this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So couple things going on. 1st was an oversight in how I was interacting with the dates. Trying to make things easier on my non-programming mind, I didn't adjust the initial qtrs- mths array to 0 based, so adjusted for that, and also set an actual day (initially I figured this would not be an issue since I was only setting a month on a new Date() and each time would reflect whatever the current day was (obviously had not thought this through since any month with a 31 would mess that up, and in the end, still caused issues). So new date set up:

```
const qtrs = [{qtr: 1, mths: [0,1,2]}, {qtr: 2, mths: [3,4,5]}, {qtr: 3, mths: [6,7,8]}, {qtr: 4, mths: [9,10,11]} ]

const currentMth = new Date().getMonth()
console.log(currentMth)

const currentQtr = qtrs.filter(({mths}) => mths.includes(currentMth))
console.log(currentQtr)

const compDates = currentQtr[0].mths.map(i => new Date(new Date(new Date(new Date().setMonth(i)).setDate(1)).setHours(0,0,0,0)).toISOString())

console.log("comp", compDates)
```

Then, with @Peterrabbit 's reminder, I scrapped what I was doing and started over, with what is below as a working result. The main difference is setting up an empty object to assign values and then push into the hours array, and also, needing to review the docs on how Array.find() and Array.filter() return results. Array.find() returns the first item that matches criteria, where filter can be used to do the opposite, and using .includes, makes this easy. Not that Array.find() cant be used to do this, but this seemed more straightforward to me at least. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599790/14330332)

```
data.forEach(i => {
let newObj = {} 

let itemsDate = i.hours.map(x => { let adjustMth = new Date(x.date).getMonth() + 1; return (new Date(new Date(new Date(new Date().setMonth(adjustMth)).setDate(1)).setHours(0,0,0,0)).toISOString())})
console.log("itemsDate", itemsDate)

let getTotal = i.hours[0].total
console.log(getTotal)

let result = compDates.filter(y => !itemsDate.includes(y))
console.log("result:", result)

if (result.length) {
    result.forEach(d => {
        newObj = {
        count: 0,
      date: d,
      total: getTotal
    };
    i.hours.push(newObj)
   } )
} else {
    console.log(false)
}

i.hours.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
});

console.log(i)
return i 
 })
 
 console.log("adjust: ", data)
```

It is not elegant javascript in any way, but my brain apparently needs to spell it out step by step. Here is a result of the console logs/ adjusted data object:

```
"current month: ", 5
"current quarter: ", [{
  mths: [3, 4, 5],
  qtr: 2
}]
"comp", ["2023-04-01T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-05-01T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-06-01T07:00:00.000Z"]
"itemsDate", ["2023-05-01T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-06-01T07:00:00.000Z"]
40
"result:", ["2023-04-01T07:00:00.000Z"]
"itemsDate", ["2023-04-01T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-06-01T07:00:00.000Z"]
46.67
"result:", ["2023-05-01T07:00:00.000Z"]
"adjust: ", [{
  _id: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  client: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  contracts: {
    monthHours: 40,
    total: 120,
    type: "Quarterly"
  },
  fullName: "Johnny Cochrane",
  hours: [{
  count: 0,
  date: "2023-04-01T07:00:00.000Z",
  total: 40
}, {
  count: 6,
  date: "2023-5",
  total: 40
}, {
  count: 2,
  date: "2023-6",
  total: 40
}]
}, {
  _id: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
  client: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e",
  contracts: {
    monthHours: 46.67,
    total: 140,
    type: "Quarterly"
  },
  fullName: "Sheila Thompson",
  hours: [{
  count: 5.5,
  date: "2023-4",
  total: 46.67
}, {
  count: 0,
  date: "2023-05-01T07:00:00.000Z",
  total: 46.67
}, {
  count: 2,
  date: "2023-6",
  total: 46.67
}]
}]
```